# how to manage large arrays

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management

I have a c++ program that uses several very large arrays of doubles, and I want to reduce the memory footprint of this particular part of the program. Currently, I'm allocating 100 of them and they can be 100 Mb each.

Now, I do have the advantage, that eventually parts of these arrays become obsolete during later parts of the program's execution, and there is little need to ever have the whole of any one of then in memory at any one time.

My question is this:

Is there any way of telling the OS after I have created the array with new or malloc that a part of it is unnecessary any more ?
I'm coming to the conclusion that the only way to achieve this is going to be to declare an array of pointers, each of which may point to a chunk say 1Mb of the desired array, so that old chunks that are not needed any more can be reused for new bits of the array. This seems to me like writing a custom memory manager which does seem like a bit of a sledgehammer, that's going to create a bit of a performance hit as well

I can't move the data in the array because it is going to cause too many thread contention issues. the arrays may be accessed by any one of a large number of threads at any time, though only one thread ever writes to any given array.

Comment: Often the answer to very-large-array problems is to use *sparse arrays* -- a data structure that looks like an array, but really only stores the relevant elements. This works if much of the array is empty space. Is that true here, or at some point do you actually need all the elements in a given array?

Comment: Would a platform-specific solution be acceptable? Posix allows you to `mmap` a large region, and then `munmap` parts of it once you've finished with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the operating system. POSIX - including Linux - has the system call `madvise` to do improve memory performance. From the man page:

> The  madvise()  system  call advises the kernel about how to handle paging input/output in the address range beginning at address addr and with size length bytes.  It allows an application to tell the kernel how it expects to use some mapped or shared memory areas, so that the kernel can choose appropriate read-ahead and caching techniques.  This call does not influence the semantics of the application (except in the case of MADV_DONTNEED), but may influence its performance.  The kernel is free to ignore the advice.

See the man page of `madvise` for more information.

**Edit:** Apparently, the above description was not clear enough. So, here are some more details, and some of them are specific to Linux.

You can use `mmap` to allocate a block of memory (directly from the OS instead of the libc), that is not backed by any file. For large chunks of memory, `malloc` is doing exactly the same thing. You have to use `munmap` to release the memory - regardless of the usage of `madvise`:

```
void* data = ::mmap(nullptr, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
// ...
::munmap(data, size);
```

If you want to get rid of some parts of this chunk, you can use `madvise` to tell the kernel to do so:

```
madvise(static_cast<unsigned char*>(data) + 7 * page_size,
    3 * page_size, MADV_DONTNEED);
```

The address range is still valid, but it is no longer backed - neither by physical RAM nor by storage. If you access the pages later, the kernel will allocate some new pages on the fly and re-initialize them to zero. Be aware, that the *dontneed* pages are also part of the virtual memory size of the process. It might be necessary to make some configuration changes to the virtual memory management, e.g. activating over-commit.

Comment: You mustn't `free` or `delete` the memory afterwards though; that might try to reuse the memory that's no longer available to the process.

Comment: Just looking through the man page for mmap. what are the benefits of calling with MAP_NORESERVE vs MAP_ANONYMOUS or both ?

Comment: MAP_NORESERVE is about memory over-commit, i.e. will the initial memory allocation succeed, although it might happen, that it can't be provided later. You shouldn't use MAP_NORESERVE, if you plan to use the memory immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to answer if we had more details.

1°) The answer to the question "Is there any way of telling the OS after I have created the array with new or malloc that a part of it is unnecessary any more ?" is "not really". That's the point of C and C++, and any language that let you handle memory manually.

2°) If you're using C++ and not C, you should not be using malloc.

3°) Nor arrays, unless for a very specific reason. Use a std::vector.

4°) Preferably, if you need to change often the content of the array and reduce the memory footprint, use a linked list (std::list), though it'll be more expensive to "access" individually the content of the list (but will be almost as fast if you only iterate through it).

Answer (score 1):

A `std::deque` with pointers to `std::array<double,LARGE_NUMBER>` may do the job, but you better make a dedicated container with the deque, so you can remap the indexes and most importantly, define when entries are not used anymore.

The dedicated container can also contain a read/write lock, so it can be used in a thread-safe way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using lists instead of arrays. Of course list is 'heavyer' than array but on the other hand it is easy to reconstruct a list so that you can throw away a part of it when it becomes obsolete. You could also use a wrapper which would only contain indexes saying which part of the list is up-to-date and which part may be reused.
This will help you improve performance, but will require a little bit more (reusable) memory.

Comment: don't lists have to be accessed in sequence though. Iterating through the list to access element 1000000+ is going to be slow

Comment: If only a part of list is being used at a time, this will not be really slow. In fact, it depends on the implementation of list. The list in std is implemented very optimally and the performance mustn't be much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Allocating by chunk and `delete[]`-ing and `new[]`-ing on the way seems like the good solution. It may be possible to do as little as memory management as possible. Do not reuse chunk yourself, simply deallocate old one and allocate new chunks when needed.